# Custom Maps, GEODJANGO, TILEMILL, OSM, OPENLAYERS,

Tags: openlayers, geodjango, tilemill

I am trying to learn on designing online maps and showing data on maps. There are so many information on the net but they are messy. I hope someone can answer this question so that the process be clearer.

I am using Django, GeoDjango for my site. So i have a postgresql database with postgis enabled. From my searches i have taken the below steps.

1- Use osm( openstreetmap ) to get map data. I need only one country data so i have found http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/europe/turkey-130627.shp.zip link to load osm data as shape file.
2- Use tilemill to style the map. Export as MBTiles.

3-  ???  Now i have MBTiles but how can i use those tiles. This is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to figure out what the question is, but it looks like you're trying to find a tile server to make those MBTiles online. Look to [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have exported map as .MBtiles(Sqlite database), you can use TMS Layer of openlayer to show your map. checkout this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62451/openlayers-tms-limit-zoom-and-extent) for implementation of TMS layer.